# How to get unique string from variable in bash

Tags: bash

Hello I would like to ask how can I get unique string from variable.

```
while read -r line      
    do
        route=$(echo $line | awk -F'[:]' '{print $2}') #get path from log file
        if [ "`dirname "$route"`" == "`xrealpath "$PWD"`" ]; then #compare path from log file with $PWD
            name=$(echo $line | awk -F'[:]' '{print $1}') #take name from 1st column in log file
        fi
        if ! [ "$name" == "$help_name" ]; then
            echo $name
            help_name=$name
            pom=$pom:$name
        fi
    done < $WEDI_RC
```

Sample logfile:

```
proj.sh:/Users/Tom/Documents/proj.sh:2015-03-21:1
proj1.sh:/Users/Tom/Documents/proj.sh:2015-03-21:1
proj.sh:/Users/Tom/Documents/proj.sh:2015-03-21:2
proj1.sh:/Users/Tom/Documents/proj.sh:2015-03-21:2
proj.sh:/Users/Tom/Documents/proj.sh:2015-03-21:3
proj1.sh:/Users/Tom/Documents/proj.sh:2015-03-21:3
```

How can I echo each unique just one time?

My output now looks something like this:

```
proj.sh
proj1.sh
proj.sh
proj1.sh
proj.sh
:proj.sh:proj1.sh:proj.sh:proj1.sh:proj.
```

Expecting output:

```
proj.sh
proj1.sh
```

I don't know how much files can be readed in while cycle.
We cannot use any temporary files
Thank you

Comment: If you want to avoid any duplicates then you need to keep a list/array of every value you've seen not just the most recent one (that only works for sorted input).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer for Original Version of This Question

This uses the associative array `seen` to keep track of what names have been seen:

```
declare -A seen
while read -r line    
... blabla ...
do
    if [ -z "${seen[$name]}" ]; then
        echo $name
        seen["$name"]=1
        pom=$pom:$name
    fi
done < "$WEDI_RC"
```

#### Working Example (No `blabla`)

Let us start with this file:

```
$ cat file
proj.sh
proj1.sh
proj.sh
proj1.sh
proj.sh
```

We will run this code (note that `...blabla...` has been removed and the loop now reads in `name` directly):

```
$ cat script.sh
declare -A seen
while read -r name
do
    if [ -z "${seen[$name]}" ]; then
        echo $name
        seen["$name"]=1
        pom=$pom:$name
    fi
done < file
declare -p pom
```

This is the result:

```
$ bash script.sh
proj.sh
proj1.sh
declare -- pom=":proj.sh:proj1.sh"
```

#### Answer for Revised Question

In the revised question, the following code appears:

```
    route=$(echo $line | awk -F'[:]' '{print $2}') #get path from log file
    if [ "`dirname "$route"`" == "`xrealpath "$PWD"`" ]; then #compare path from log file with $PWD
        name=$(echo $line | awk -F'[:]' '{print $1}') #take name from 1st column in log file
```

This means that, as the code runs, `name` may never be set depending on the current directory when the script is run.  This would explain the error messages reported in the comments.

Comment: no it didn't worked for me:
Tom$ ./wedi -l
./wedi: line 16: declare: -A: invalid option
declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]
wedi
./wedi: line 150: proj1.sh: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".sh")

Comment: @tom That is the message that occurs if `name` is never defined.  In the  code as given in the question, the loop reads in `line` and then `... blabla ...` occurs.  It is necessary that `... blabla ...` define the variable `name` in order for something useful to happen.  Does your `... blabla ...` define the variable `name`?

Comment: @Tom Please see the updated answer for code that is analogous to yours but is complete and runs (no blabla).

Comment: I add whole while cycle with "blabla", we cannnot use any temporary files

Comment: So, that would appear to mean that `blabla` did not define `name`.  _"we cannnot use any temporary files"_  Why did you mention this?  Temporary files are not used in this code.

Comment: oh sorry, I thought that you create new file with "$cat file" and there add names from while cycle